# sql how to invoke inner join to get names with listing

Tags: mysql

i am new to mysql and i have been facing issues trying on how to use inner join to get the names of all the users who posted a listing. Any help or tips would be appreciated! Have a nice day! the table is linked together via foreign keys.

the desired result will look something like:

```
userName, itemName, itemDescription, price
```

the code for my sql is below.

```
CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `snapsell`;
USE `snapsell`;

CREATE TABLE USER_LIST(
id INT(6)  AUTO_INCREMENT unique not null,
userName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL unique,
email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
registeredDate timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
primary key(id)
);

insert into user_list(userName,email) values 
('John', 'john123@google.com'),
('Tom', 'Tommy123@google.com'),
('Javier', 'javier125@google.com'),
('Deft', 'Deft45620@google.com');


create table listing_list(
id INT(6)  AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
itemName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
itemDescription VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
price DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,
fk_poster_id int not null ,
created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
unique(id),
constraint fk_poster_id
foreign key(fk_poster_id)
references USER_LIST(id)
on delete cascade
);

insert into listing_list (itemName,itemDescription,price,fk_poster_id) values 
('Pen',' It is a writing instrument used to apply ink to a surface, usually paper, for writing or drawing','1.50','2'),
('Pencil',' Dark blue pencil, used to draw on a surface, usually paper, for writing or drawing','0.50','1'),
('Paper','A stack of 50 foolscap paper.','2','1');


create table offer_list(
id int(6)  auto_increment Primary key unique,
offer int not null,
fk_listing_id int not null ,
fk_offeror_id int not null ,
created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
constraint `fk_listing_id`
foreign key (`fk_listing_id`)
references listing_list(id)
on delete cascade,
constraint `fk_offeror_id`
foreign key (`fk_offeror_id`)
references user_list(id)
on delete cascade
);

insert into offer_list(offer,fk_listing_id,fk_offeror_id) values 
(2,1,3),
(3,1,4),
(0.5,2,2),
(9,1,3),
(1.50,3,5);


Alter table user_list add column password varchar(255) not null;
select* from listing_list;
```

Comment: Please show us your expected results.

Comment: Where are you trying to use `INNER JOIN`?  In what way does it fail?

Answer (score 0):

I you just want the names of the user who posted at least one offer, you can use `exists`:

```
select u.*
from user_list u
where exists (select 1 from offer_list o where o.fk_offeror_id = u.id)
```

If you want one row per user/offer tuple and more columns, then you can `join` as follows:

```
select u.userName, l.itemName, l.itemDescription, l.price
from user_list u
inner join offer_list o on o.fk_offeror_id = u.id
inner join listing_list l on l.id = o.fk_listing_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the table `offer_list` for this requirement.
Join `user_list` with `listing_list`:

```
select u.userName, l.itemName, l.itemDescription, l.price
from user_list u inner join listing_list l
on l.fk_poster_id = u.id
order by u.userName, l.itemName
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nDH3Yq4TGeAkmbvj3m3brB/0).
Results:

```
| userName | itemName | itemDescription                                                                                   | price |
| -------- | -------- | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | ----- |
| John     | Paper    | A stack of 50 foolscap paper.                                                                     | 2     |
| John     | Pencil   | Dark blue pencil, used to draw on a surface, usually paper, for writing or drawing                | 0.5   |
| Tom      | Pen      | It is a writing instrument used to apply ink to a surface, usually paper, for writing or drawing  | 1.5   |
```